# Really Slow Performing MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been tasked with supporting an application for a client that is painfully slow.  I enabled MySQL slow_query_log and found a few queries that seem to be the culprit.  I'm a little confused as to what this query is doing, but any advise on how I could rewrite this would be helpful.

```
SELECT
    table_a.id AS table_a_id_1,
    table_a2.id AS table_a_id_2
FROM
    table_a,
    table_b
LEFT JOIN
    table_a AS table_a2
ON
    table_a.value = table_a2.value
WHERE
    table_a.value_id = 112 AND
    table_a2.value_id = 113 AND
    table_a.status != table_a2.status AND
    table_a.id = table_b.id;
```

To me it looks like the query is selecting the same data twice from a single table, then doing some comparisons with the selected data, as well as performing a join with table_b as well. Here is the log from MySQL referencing this query's execution.

```
Query_time: 160.854398
Lock_time: 0.000139
Rows_sent: 12
Rows_examined: 10339025
```

Any advise you could provide would be helpful!

Comment: I don't even think that query is valid... Are you sure it runs correctly? Have you made any changes to the query before posting it?

Comment: I didn't think it was valid either, it looks really odd to me.  However, it runs without producing errors and returns rows.  The only changes I made to the query was to replace table names with table_a and table_b...etc.

I'll check and see if I can post the actual full query if you think that would help. It's really even more confusing...LOL!

Comment: It is an extremly bad idea to combine explict and implicit joins (and using implicit joins at all is a SQL antipattern). Just fixing to use explict joins wil probaly help, then you need to fix the parts of your query that are flat wrong. See my comments in @GordonLinoff's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that the query plan is creating a cross join, as specified in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT table_a.id AS table_a_id_1,
       table_a2.id AS table_a_id_2
FROM table_a join
     table_b
     on table_a.id = table_b.id LEFT JOIN
     table_a AS table_a2
     ON table_a.value = table_a2.value
WHERE table_a.value_id = 112 AND
      table_a2.value_id = 113 AND
      table_a.status != table_a2.status
```

This also suggests that indexes on table_a.id and table_a.value and table_b.id might help a lot.

Now, you might be able to simplify this query a lot.  For instance, it seems to be getting pairs of 112, 113 in table_a where the statuses are different.  I don't really see where table_b is being used, unless for some filtering criterion.  You can get this list more efficiently by doiing something like:

```
SELECT table_a.id AS table_a_id_1,
       table_a2.id AS table_a_id_2
FROM (select ta.* from table_a ta where ta.value_id = 112) ta join
     (select ta.* from table_a ta where ta.value_id = 113) ta2
     ON ta.value = ta2.value and
        ta.status != ta2.status
```

Comment: table_a2.value_id = 113 needs to be in the where clause or you are converting a left join to an inner join. and table_a.status != table_a2.status  needs a coalesce to avoid comparing a null value to a value.

Comment: I'm doing a join here, and intentially converting the left join to a regular join.  I think the left join is redundant because the where clause in the original query ensures that NULL values on the table_a2 side are dropped.  However, I've never really thought about a left join where the "on" condition does not reference the first table, so I'm not sure what SQL specifies (or what mysql does) in this case.  Perhaps it does a cross join on the first two tables and this is left joined to the third table?